# I sent some monero to a "standard XMR" address while my wallet uses base58 format, was it lost?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, synchronization, transaction-confirmation, sweep-transaction

The sender was having some troubles to withdraw using the base58 format, which starts with a 8. So I used this website thinking the worst that could happen is me having to manually sweep the address with the private key

https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html

And I gave him the correspondent "standard XMR" address shown on line 15, which starts with a 4.

Transaction has plenty of confirmations and was not automatically detected by the wallet. So I'm trying to import in Monero Gui a private key using as the address the "standard XMR" public address, and using the private spend and view key from the wallet itself (note, it's a different address starting with 4 than the main account shows). It doesn't work, it just errors out and doesn't let me proceed.

Was the coins lost for good?

I think I need a way to calculate to hash the private spend and view key from the subadress itself, like it's very crudely explained here

https://monerodocs.org/public-address/subaddress/

After that it should just be a matter of importing in the wallet, if anyone has any have idea how to do that please share...

Comment: have you checked the TX to see if it went through?  (Don't enter you seed or private keys into ANY website.  just begging to be robbed.) A '4' address is usually the main while an '8' is a sbaddress.

Comment: It did went through, I have the tx id.
Actually I found a solution which is quite old, I'm unable to compile that program
https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8l28sk/comment/dzdckul/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3